# How to programmatically disable user access control (or equivalent) on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6, windows-security

My company maintains software on a number of windows mobile devices. The users of these devices are scattered throughout the country. Every time we needed to update the software we had to physically drive out and meet each user and put the new software on the device. So I wrote an updater.

The updater checks in with the server and downloads the new software and no one has to drive anywhere. It all works pretty well except for the fact that it prompts the user to ask if they want to run the software and it only gives them about 3 seconds to decide.

A lot of our user aren't the most tech savvy to put it mildly and just won't click ok and don't have the ability to get to that ok button when it flashes up.

Is it possible to disable user access control (well that's what it would be called on the desktop versions of windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the apps are unsigned, which is why you're getting the prompt.

You need to install a security policy on the devices which suppresses this prompt. The (retired) [document on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416355.aspx) details this.

You need to set the Unsigned Prompt Policy (4122) to the value `1` to suppress the prompt. Getting the policy onto the devices is another matter entirely. The [Security Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416315.aspx) overview goes into a little detail on this.

You would probably be better off getting the applications signed, which *should* bypass the security prompt, which is a far better option than making the devices insecure by suppressing the prompt.